# C# Auto Update List insted of .clear and refill the list

Tags: c#, list

In my program I populate a list, but the next time I rerun my loop again I .clear the list to repopulate it again because some items in the list might update. How ever, is there somehow I can make it so it just auto updates the items in the list so I can't have to .clear and re add the items?

```
         _players.Clear();
            _weapons.Clear();
            _entities.Clear();

            var localPlayerPtr = Smurf.Memory.Read<IntPtr>(Smurf.ClientBase + Offsets.Misc.LocalPlayer);


            LocalPlayer = new LocalPlayer(localPlayerPtr);
            LocalPlayerWeapon = LocalPlayer.GetCurrentWeapon(localPlayerPtr);

for (var i = 0; i < _capacity; i++)
            {
                var entity = new BaseEntity(GetEntityPtr(i));

                if (!entity.IsValid)
                    continue;

                if (entity.IsPlayer())
                    _players.Add(new Player(GetEntityPtr(i)));
                else if (entity.IsWeapon())
                    _weapons.Add(new LocalPlayerWeapon(GetEntityPtr(i)));
                else
                    _entities.Add(new BaseEntity(GetEntityPtr(i)));
            }
            _lastUpdate = timeStamp;
```

Comment: Repopulating is perfectly fine. Do you have concerns (e.g. performance, memory issues, etc.)?

Comment: @Sinatr No, I don't I just thought it would be best practive to do it anyway to prevent performance or memory issues at a later stage. Such as using a dictornay or tuple or something simular to day.

Answer (score 0):

Total repopulation of a list should be a fast enough way to deal with this. If you really need to go the other way, then your alternative is to when you run your loop:

1. Check your new element if it exists, and if yes, update it in the list (`_players[index] = newPlayer;` or something similar). Check by ID, or some other property that identifies your objects.
2. If it doesn't exist, add it as a new item to the list.
3. Store your new element in a separate list to keep track. (let's call it `changesList`)
4. (optional, if you need to prune) When you've finished going through all your new items, compare `changesList` with your other lists (you can probably use the `Except(IEnumerable<T> list)` method, and remove the objects that were not used.

Comment: Answer can be shortened to "implement [INotifyCollectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)".